# Rearranging the columns of a data frame

Tags: r

Given a data frame, I'd like to rearrange it and return another data frame of 2 columns. The 2 columns of this data frame are made up of any 2 elements of a row in the original data frame. So we will have `C(ncol,2) * nrow` number of rows in the second data frame. Here's an example. Given the data frame `z`, I'd like to return `x`. How can I do this?

```
> z = data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(4,5,6), C = c(7,8,9))
> z
  A B C
1 1 4 7
2 2 5 8
3 3 6 9
> x
  A B
1 1 4
2 1 7
3 4 7
4 2 5
5 2 8
6 5 8
7 3 6
8 3 9
9 6 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, you could try:

```
 matrix(apply(z, 1, combn,2), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
 #      [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    1    4
 #[2,]    1    7
 #[3,]    4    7
 #[4,]    2    5
 #[5,]    2    8
 #[6,]    5    8
 #[7,]    3    6
 #[8,]    3    9
 #[9,]    6    9
```

To get `data.frame` as output

```
 setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(apply(z, 1, combn,2), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)), LETTERS[1:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```
newz <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(split(z, 1:nrow(z)), function(x) 
    t(combn(x,2)))), 
c("A","B"))
newz

#     A B
# 1.1 1 4
# 1.2 1 7
# 1.3 4 7
# 2.1 2 5
# 2.2 2 8
# 2.3 5 8
# 3.1 3 6
# 3.2 3 9
# 3.3 6 9
```

This generates the new rows using all combinations if the columns via `combn()`. If you hate the default rownames, you can get rid of them with

```
rownames(newz)<-NULL
newz
#   A B
# 1 1 4
# 2 1 7
# 3 4 7
# 4 2 5
# 5 2 8
# 6 5 8
# 7 3 6
# 8 3 9
# 9 6 9
```